# my string doesn't appear in my database

Tags: android, database, string, android-edittext

So i used a editText called "add", when i click on the button he have to insert into a table a title (string) and amount(int) and comments (string) .
the title is like this : String title = add.getText().toString();
But it does not appear in the table .
Plus when i had forgotten the "getText()" it displayed : android.widget.EditText@43e41168 .
I dont know why ...
(Sorry for my bad english, i'm french ^^).

Comment: What type of table are you trying to insert into? Database?

Comment: the table is : title STRING, amount INT, comment STRING ;

Comment: i tried to pass : income.insertTable(title, 100, " test"); where income is a Table object and where the methode for insertTable is like this :  public void insertTable(String title,int amount,String comment){
  String sql = "INSERT INTO "+getTbName()+" (title,amount,comment) VALUES('"+title+"',"+amount+",'"+comment+"')";
  getDb().execSQL(sql);
 }

Comment: Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection before you continue :) In terms of your question, please provide some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Table income;
private Table expense;
String title,comment;
int amount;

EditText add;
Button add_btn;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    expense = new Table(db,helper.TABLE_1);
    income = new Table(db,helper.TABLE_2);
    add_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    add = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add);
    add_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    title = add.getText().toString();
    income.insertTable(title, 100, " test");
    expense.insertTable("another title", 50, "blah blah");
}
```

}

this is the right answer, i had to move the String title from the onCreate to the onClick.